# ITMS-90512: Invalid sdk value

Tags: ios, swift, review

Trying to Submit for Review application, but I constantly get this result:
ITMS-90512: Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in MyApplicationName.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is 14.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 13.5.
I tried different versions of xcode, changed the target settings, but constantly this result.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Your application is targeting minimum iOS Version 14.0, which is not publicly released yet.

Go to Your Target -> General -> Deployment Info and set iOS target version accordingly.

[image]